# How to insert periodic newlines into a file with 1 incredibly long line

Tags: unix, text-processing

I have a text file with just 1 line, but 2G characters.

I need to find something within the file, but the line is too long to open in any editor - either on Unix, or if I ftp it over to my PC...

Is there a quick / simple way to insert a newline, for example, every 120 characters?

Comment: using which program language? is this related to programming?

Comment: have you tried using `less` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28Unix%29. from my experience, it does a good job handling large files.

Comment: @Colin - less will display it on the screen for me, and wrap the line a billion times. But then, if I pipe less's output into a file, the resulting file will still be just one line.

Comment: It's a close call, but I'd argue text processing probably is on-topic (though http://unix.stackexchange.com/ would be a better bet).  I mean, how many non-programmers need to do this sort of thing...

Comment: BTW, here's a duplicate on unix.SE : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60219/is-there-a-command-line-tool-to-insert-line-breaks-into-a-long-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Fold` command does that, so if you want to wrap after 120..

```
fold -w120 fie > newfile
```

Comment: This one works. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/\(.\{120\}\)/\1\n/g' file.txt
```

if you need to create a new file, then just redirect the output:

```
sed 's/\(.\{120\}\)/\1\n/g' file.txt > new_file.txt
```

Following an example of for 4 characters per line

```
[fotanus@thing ~]$ cat test.txt 
qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
[fotanus@thing ~]$ sed 's/\(.\{4\}\)/\1\n/g' test.txt > a.txt
[fotanus@thing ~]$ cat a.txt 
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
qqqq
```

Comment: It's running... holding my fingers crossed.

Comment: please accept @vidit answer, I'm sure it is the best way to do.

Comment: It doesn't work. new_file.txt is also just one gigantic line

Comment: @Marjeta interesting,perhaps the redirect doesn’t work? work in the terminal output. Anyway, `fold` is the right tool for this job, not `sed`

Comment: Why wouldn't redirect work? Yes, fold works - thanks for pointing me to the correct answer.

Comment: @Marjeta I'm not sure. I added an example in my answer that shows that it also works. But well, no point in go deeper on this since we have a better option :-)

Comment: @fotanus that's how I did it, except for difference in file names. And the resulting file was slightly longer in characters, but still just one line. I guess we have a different version of sed. Or maybe it's AIX thing (acronym for: somewhAt sImilar to uniX). Or it must be the internet gremlins... I agree that there's no sense in going deeper, and I very much appreciate that you pointed me to the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this line:

```
 sed -r 's/.{120}/&\n/g' file
```

if you want to write the change back to your original file:

```
sed -ir 's/.{120}/&\n/g' file
```

for example:

file has 100 `s`, every 12 chars add a linebreak:

```
kent$  cat file                   
ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss


kent$  sed -r 's/.{12}/&\n/g' file
ssssssssssss
ssssssssssss
ssssssssssss
ssssssssssss
ssssssssssss
ssssssssssss
ssssssssssss
ssssssssssss
ssss
```

Comment: Actually, I don't want to overwrite the original file.

Comment: Ugh!
sed: illegal option -- r
Usage:  sed [-n] Script [File ...]
        sed [-n] [-e Script] ... [-f Script_file] ... [File ...]

Answer (score 0):

if you do not mind creating another file. Tested this with `bash` on `linux`. Here blah.out is the input file

```
while read -r -d '' -n 120 record; do echo $record; done<blah.out > blah2.out
```